# Access function from model class or controller class from helper file with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know it is not a good experience. But just I want to know it is possible to access a function from model or controller class from a helper file in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant you use something like this i believe.

```
$Helper =& load_class('Helper'); //Load the (Helper Loader) $this->load->helper becomes $helper
$Class = $Helper('Name of class');
```

But i do not see why you should do this

Can't you just create an extra model class like

```
class DBFile
{
   ...
}
```

then create your Model

```
class Model_SomeName extends DBFile
{
  /*So no this uses DBFile instead of CI_Database or w.e it is*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, you will have to load the helper class first like this:

```
$this->load->helper('name of helper class');
```

More Info:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/array_helper.html

Comment: Thank you for your response...!!Actually I want reverse(model method from helper).I need to access a model function from helper class not wiseversa...?